# C# SetCursorPosition not working in a game

Tags: c#, set, position, cursor

I trying to change the gun target using this code

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(20,20);
```

Its working on my desktop but cursor is does not change on a game.
How can i change my cursor position in a 3d game?

[Game Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmVsW.jpg)

Edit:
As a result of research, SetCurusorPos is not working owing to anti-cheat system.
Valorant vanguard is not allowed to external mouse moves

Comment: Stop trying to cheat at games.

Comment: There is a better solution for this, Valorant knows if whenever something is not quite right for example when an input is coming from a Win32 API. Current most cheat software would create a fake mouse driver and control it as if it's a real mouse but is actually controlled using their software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valorant, the game you're trying to change the cursor with, is ran as an elevated process with anti cheat, it probably hooked the mouse and prevented outside modification. Try running Visual Studio as administrator and debug your app.

Comment: I already tried run my app as administrator, but it still not working